# print the contents of a list <> in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, textbox

good morning, I'm having trouble with the following. I'm reading the contents of a file (. txt) in a folder, but what I want now is to print the contents of the files into a textbox, but I'm having problems with that.

what I have to code this is.

```
FolderBrowserDialog Lectura = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult response = Lectura.ShowDialog();

if (response == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Lectura.SelectedPath);
    ListBox archivosListBox = new ListBox();
    archivosListBox.Items.AddRange(files);

    int tamanoLista = archivosListBox.Items.Count;
    List <string[]> Miarchivo = new List<string[]>();

    foreach (string archivos in archivosListBox.Items)
    {
        Miarchivo.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(archivos));
    }

    string[] leerArchivo;
    int j =Miarchivo.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i<tamanoLista; i++)
    {
        leerArchivo = Miarchivo[i];

        for (int k = 0; k < Miarchivo[i].Count(); k++)
        {
            //textBox1.Text += leerArchivo[k] ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having?  Compiler errors?  Exceptions? Wrong data?

Comment: what happens is that I printed, but since everything on one line, it does not print line by line, is leaving me all the content on a single line.

Comment: @EvanL: The `List<string[]>` is because every item in the list will hold the result of `File.ReadAllLines()` (first foreach loop) and that is a string[]

Comment: @Abbas Yep removing... i posted before reading well enough.

Comment: @JeissonNiño is your textbox set to multi-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place a newline character after each entry in your TextBox. Change your code to following:

```
for (int k = 0; k < Miarchivo[i].Count(); k++)
{
    textBox1.Text += leerArchivo[k] + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

More reading: [**Environment.NewLine Property (MSDN)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @JeissonNiño Thank him by upvoting and/or marking this as the answer by checking the green check mark below the vote buttons =)

Comment: Using StringBuilder instead of textBox1.Text += is better here: it allows to avoid constant repainting of the textBox1

Comment: @Abbas says I can not, until a few minutes;)

Comment: Good point, although that wasn't the OPs problem, but in terms of performance you're right! :)

Comment: @Abbas, almost 4 years later I found this in a search. THANK YOU!! I kept thinking my code was wrong for something similar, and all I needed was the " += " instead of just " = ".

Answer (score 3):

Use `ReadAllText` instead of `ReadAllLines` and replace entire loop with string join:

```
List<string> Miarchivo = new List<string>();
foreach (string archivos in archivosListBox.Items)    
    Miarchivo.Add(File.ReadAllText(archivos));

textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Miarchivo);
```

Another (probably better solution) is usage of `TextBox.Lines` property and getting files content with LINQ:

```
textBox1.Lines = archivosListBox.Items
                     .Cast<string>()
                     .SelectMany(archivos => File.ReadLines(archivos))
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for the LINQ solution, much more elegant.  Avoids object creation (`StringBuilder`), loops and eliminates the need for `NewLine` delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather update `textBox1.Text` *once* in order to avoid *constant repainting*:

```
    if (response == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Lectura.SelectedPath);
        ListBox archivosListBox = new ListBox();
        archivosListBox.Items.AddRange(files);

        int tamanoLista = archivosListBox.Items.Count;

        List <string[]> Miarchivo = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (string archivos in archivosListBox.Items)
        {
          Miarchivo.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(archivos));
        }

        // Output into textBox1
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(String[] leerArchivo in Miarchivo) 
          foreach(String item in leerArchivo) {
            if (sb.Length > 0) 
              sb.AppendLine(); // <- Or other deriver, e.g. sb.Append(';');

            sb.Append(item);
          }

        // Pay attention: textBox1 has been updated once only
        textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why the if, couldn't you just do: `foreach(String item in leerArchivo) { sb.AppendLine(item); }` ? Now it looks ugly and does unnecessary checks.

Comment: @Abbas: To avoid NewLine at the end of the text: "A NewLine B" vs. "A NewLine B NewLine"

Comment: Then I could do this *once* at the end of the inner loop: `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it sounds like you just need a line break at the end of each line:

```
textBox1.Text += leerArchivo[k] + Environment.NewLine ;
```